# How to extract the JSON encoded POST parameters in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have passed JSON encoded parameters by POST which we have captured and decoded in another PHP file. I have used the following code to do that.

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$entityBody = json_decode($entityBody, true);
```

I have passed the JSON encoded parameters as follows:

```
{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "abcd",
    "imei": "1234"
}
```

Here my code works perfectly fine. However, I want to get all the parameters into a single object so that we can store them efficiently because otherwise there will be too many ifs and elses to get each parameter. So I have encoded the parameters as follows:

```
device = {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "abcd",
    "imei": "1234"
}
```

But it is not working. Being new to JSON and PHP I do not know how to handle such cases. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The last "json" example is not valid JSON.

Comment: Are you setting a POST field named "device", or is that second code block the entire body?

Comment: you need to get valid json as said andre, then you decode into array with no problems

Comment: I don't get it, could please post the code you use to send the data?

Answer (score 1):

use `json_decode($_POST['device'], true)` since your actually passing a parameter called 'device' to the php file.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass json objects as follow:

```
 {"device" :  {
 "id": "5",
 "name": "abcd",
 "imei": "1234"
}}
```

or if you have an array of devices

```
 {"device" :  [{
 "id": "5",
 "name": "abcd",
 "imei": "1234"}
]}
```